# Does calling window.close() terminate the session from IIS also?

Tags: .net, vbscript

I want to know that when we call `window.close` then does this also terminate the session on IIS?

I am writing below code and I am trying to terminate the session of the user from IIS.

```
  Sub OnClickLogout() 
      dim Answer, msg
      Msg = "This will terminate the session and close the browser. Do you want to continue?"
      Answer = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Error")
      if Answer = vbYes then
          window.close() ' Does this terminate the sesion of the user also?
      else
         'Return to the previous page             
      End if
  End Sub
```

If no then please tell me how can I accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the browser does not terminate the session. You can check this by adding Global.asax file to your project and get grip to session end event.

```
   void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }
```

More about session events can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583(v=vs.100).aspx

To terminate the session you should call:

```
        Page.Session.Clear();
        Page.Session.Abandon();
```